# C - fgets returns corrupt data

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

I am making a program that should read a file and do some stuff based on it, however I seem to have problem with reading the line properly.
I am using while loop with this function:

```
static int readLineFromFile(char **destination, int *allocSize, FILE *file)
{
    char *newDest;
    if (fgets(*destination, (*allocSize) - 2, file))
    {
        int strend = strlen(*destination);
        while (*(*destination + strend - 1) != '\n')
        {
            printf("\"%s\"\n", *destination);
            size_t length = (*allocSize) * 2;  //WE ARE GOING TO ALLOCATE MORE MEMORY AND KEEP READING
            newDest = realloc(*destination, length);
            if (!newDest)
            {
                free(*destination);
                return 2; //2 - FAILED ALLOC
            }
            *destination = newDest;
            fgets(*destination + strend, (length / 2), file);
            *allocSize = length;
            strend = strlen(*destination);
        }
        *(*destination+strend-1) = '\0'; //WE DONT NEED THE \n AT THE END, SO WE JUST REPLACE IT WITH \0
        printf("D %s\n", *destination);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        if (feof(file)) {   //IF NOTHING IS LEFT TO READ, WE CHECK IF IT IS BECAUSE OF EOF (1) OR AN ERROR (2)
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

where **destination is pointer to the pointer of mallocated area for the string, *allocSize pointer for the size of **destination and *file the file stream.

However, after 2nd reallocation (so, after I have had 2 lines longer than allocSize and had to realloc, doesn't matter after how many lines exactly), the printf-s (both after the realloc while cycle and at the beginning of the realloc cycle) return 5 chars correctly and 4 random ones after that ("ABCDE????" instead of "ABCDEFGHIJK..."). I thought that it was because of strtok function later in the while cycle (after reading the line), but seems it's not.

Then I found out that later in the code, I allocate space for parsed substrings of the line I loaded - and if I remove this part of the code, everything works fine again (it doesnt even matter, how many bytes I allocate, I still keep getting corrupted strings). So at this point I even started thinking if I haven't broken the OS somehow.

So, it would be nice if someone could tell me, if there is a mistake in this function, or if I should look for it elsewhere. Thanks.

Also, here are the other codes from the while cycle:
STRTOK, fileLine is the *destination from readLine:

```
char *strtokStart = malloc (strlen (fileLine)+2);
strcpy (strtokStart, fileLine);
char *strtokSave = fileLine;
strcpy (newKey, strtok_r (fileLine, "=", &strtokSave));
strcpy (newValue, strtok_r (NULL, "\n", &strtokSave));
free (strtokStart);
```

MALLOCATING additional strings:

```
config->topKey->key = (const char *) malloc(strlen(newKey) + 1);
config->topKey->value = (const char *) malloc(strlen(newValue) + 1);
if (!(config->topKey->key && config->topKey->value))
{
    printf("ALLOC FAIL\n");
    statusVal = 1;
    break;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a case for Valgrind.

Comment: I did a similar homework problem last week. Read a file and encode text and write to new file. I did it without having to allocate any memory. Why are you having to store in array first? What manipulations do you need to do?

Comment: thought as well, however I dont know what parameters I should use for valgrind to find if im not overwriting the pointers somewhere.

Comment: I have to load a file, create a list of instructions with params (config->topKey struct in the end of question) out of it, then perform these instruction (not in the order where I wouldnt have to allocate memory). So I am afraid I cant get around allocating.

Comment: Is the reallocate succeeding? You have to check to make sure it was successful before you continue.

Comment: The realloc in readLine I do check, and the config->topKey malloc also does (i indeed check that afterwards, just didn't add it here) (edited it in here)

Comment: My compiler would curse me out if I declared newDest there. Maybe yours is more forgiving.

Comment: Moved it to beginning of the function to prevent having 80 newDests.

Comment: @kubci98 Declaring a variable in a loop doesn't create 80 copies.

Comment: Hm, good to know. Though it doesn't help with the issue. :(

Comment: You're probably doing something in another part of the program that's causing undefined behavior. This is leaving a timebomb that goes off in your function to read a line.

Comment: Well sure, but how would just calling malloc (without it actually allocating more than a single byte) always result inthe same corruption? I thought that instead problem is in readline, as I would write outside what I have allocated for fileLine (*destination) and then overwrite it by malloc, but readLine function seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with readLineFromFile:

1. If the file does not end in \n, the while loop keeps allocating more memory until realloc fails. Check return code of second fgets do detect that situation!
2. Bad error handling for failed realloc: free(*destination) leaves caller with bad pointer. Best to just remove free. Or add *destination=NULL.

Otherwise readLineFromFile is fine and should work with valid input files. In the absence of invalid input files, there are probably more errors elsewhere in your code.

readLineFromFile should be called with a malloc'ed buffer, of course.